# How does arresting the ringleader of the brothel affect the story?

Tags: papers-please

At some point in the game, this woman arrives and gives me a letter (along with some other interesting stuff)

[image: The woman working for "The Pink Vice"]

In the letter is a cry for help, telling me that her boss is currently standing in line and is plotting to steal her passport so she won't ever be able to leave Arstotzka.

I decided to believe her and when her boss arrived, had him detained.
On the following day, the newspaper read *"Mastermind of human trafficking ring arrested"* (or something similar). I was glad that my decision to trust the young lady proved to be a good one, but I was always left wondering:
**What if I had let him through** (because I didn't believe/care/pay attention)**?**

Are there going to be consequences for letting him through at some point in the game? And aside from the mention in the newspaper, is something going to happen for arresting him?

With that said:

### GLORY TO ARSTOTZKA!

Comment: I know it's been a while, but @StarPilot addresses this question properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you pass him through, the sex workers will be killed the next day (story in the paper).

If you reject his entry, the sex workers will be killed the next day anyways (story in the paper).

If you detain him legally, the sex workers will not be killed. To detain him legally, you need to:

> In inspect mode, highlight his name on the note, and on his other documentation. The game will report there is a discrepancy. This will allow you to legally detain him.

Answer (score 3):

If you let him through, the paper the following day mentions that sex workers have been killed. I don't remember about other consequences.